# Can't use NSTimer update UI

Tags: ios, nstimer

In my app, I want to use a NSTimer update my UIButton instance, but my button's title didn't change as the time elapse. My code is here:

```
-(void)fireTimer{

    self.leftTime = 30;
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [self.timer fire];
}

- (void)timerAction
{
    self.leftTime--;
    NSLog(@"%d current runloop and mode is %@", self.leftTime, [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop].currentMode);

    [self.customBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"leftTime:%d", self.leftTime] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    if(self.leftTime == 0)
    {
        [self.customBtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@leftTime :%d, self.leftTime] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

And the NSLog output is correct, when *self.timeLeft == 0*, my button can change it's title correctly.

[image]

Can someone tell me what's the problem? thanks!

Comment: [self.timer fire]; is redundant in this case. This is not the cause of your issue, it's just redundant

Comment: I think this should work assuming you have created proper IBOutlet for your button . I did the same thing using UILabel and that worked for me . Just check connections for your button.

Comment: My IBOutlet is OK, I modify my code, and when the last time timer's selector execut

Comment: Is your fireTimer executed on main thread or background thread?

Comment: My viewcontroller didn't create any thread or execute any code background.

Comment: I find out the problem, I use KVO observe *self.leftTimer*, when the timer fire, I set my button.enable = NO, so it can't change the title, and when *self.leftTime == 0*, my button.enable = YES. My careless. Thanks all.

Comment: Please either remove the question or answer your own question so it can be of use to someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out the problem, I use KVO observe self.leftTimer, when the timer fire, I set my button.enable = NO, so it can't change the title, and when self.leftTime == 0, my button.enable = YES. My careless. Thanks all.